# CakePHPにてmodifiedが正しく表示されません。

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

[image: topicsテーブル][image: array画像][image: modifiedが正しく表示されない]

最近CakePHPの勉強を始めた者です。
早速エラーに苦しめられています。。。。

初歩的な問題かと思いますので、
どなたかお分かりの方、ご回答宜しくお願い致します。

## 【index.ctp】と【TopicsController】【Topic.php】のソースを記載します

### index.ctp

```
<div class="topics index">
    <h2><?php echo __('Topics'); ?></h2>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('title'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('body'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('category_id'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('created'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(' modified'); ?></th>
            <th class="actions"><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($topics as $topic): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo h($topic['Topic']['id']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($topic['Topic']['title']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($topic['Topic']['body']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($topic['Category']['name'], array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view', $topic['Category']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo h($topic['Topic']['created']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($topic['Topic']['modified']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="actions">
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', $topic['Topic']['id'])); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), array('action' => 'edit', $topic['Topic']['id'])); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete', $topic['Topic']['id']), array(), __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $topic['Topic']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
    <?php
    echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
    'format' => __('Page {:page} of {:pages}, showing {:current} records out of {:count} total, starting on record {:start}, ending on {:end}')
    ));
    ?>    </p>
    <div class="paging">
    <?php
        echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
        echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
        echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <h3><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></h3>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Topic'), array('action' => 'add')); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Categories'), array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Category'), array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Comments'), array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Comment'), array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### TopicsController

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Topics Controller
 *
 * @property Topic $Topic
 * @property PaginatorComponent $Paginator
 */
class TopicsController extends AppController {

/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $components = array('Paginator');

/**
 * index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        $this->Topic->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('topics', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }

/**
 * view method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Topic->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid topic'));
        }
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Topic.' . $this->Topic->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->set('topic', $this->Topic->find('first', $options));
    }

/**
 * add method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Topic->create();
            if ($this->Topic->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The topic has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The topic could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $categories = $this->Topic->Category->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('categories'));
    }

/**
 * edit method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Topic->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid topic'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            if ($this->Topic->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The topic has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The topic could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array('Topic.' . $this->Topic->primaryKey => $id));
            $this->request->data = $this->Topic->find('first', $options);
        }
        $categories = $this->Topic->Category->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('categories'));
    }

/**
 * delete method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function delete($id = null) {
        $this->Topic->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Topic->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid topic'));
        }
        $this->request->allowMethod('post', 'delete');
        if ($this->Topic->delete()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The topic has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The topic could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

### Topic.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Topic Model
 *
 * @property Category $Category
 * @property Comment $Comment
 */
class Topic extends AppModel {

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $validate = array(
        'title' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'body' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'category_id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'modified' => array(
            'datetime' => array(
                'rule' => array('datetime'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Category' => array(
            'className' => 'Category',
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Comment' => array(
            'className' => 'Comment',
            'foreignKey' => 'topic_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

Comment: <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort(' modified'); ?></th>
のスペースは削除しましたが、エラーは解決されないです。。。

Comment: 出力されたSQLを見ると`modified`のみ`Topic`が付いていないようです。`print_r`などで中身を確認してはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 大変恐縮ですが、「出力されたSQLを見るとmodifiedのみTopicが付いていないようです。」というのはどういうことでしょうか？
また<td><?php echo h($topic['Topic']['modified']); ?>&nbsp;</td>の後に【print_r($topic['Topic']['modified'])】すればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: ページの下に出ているデバッグ情報が「…Topic.created, modified, Category.id…」となっています。このため表示時に値が正しく取得できていないのではないかと思います。`<?php print_r($topic); ?>`で変数の中身が全て出力されるので、`<td>`の中の`&nbsp;`の後ろにでも記載してみて下さい。

Comment: Model(とTable) がどうなっているのか分からないのですが、`topics` テーブルに `modified` テーブルは存在してますか？

Comment: >pgrhoさん
画像を追加してのでご確認いただきたいのですが、
modifiedの値は取得できている気がします。

>Shironeさん
topicsテーブルにmodifiedテーブルも作っています。。。

Comment: `print_r`の出力を見ると`Category`の先頭に`modified`があり、どうもテーブル名が無いことで`Topic.modified`が`Category.modified`と認識されているように見えます。原因はちょっと思い浮かばないのですが、モデルでは何か指定されていますが？

Comment: Topic.phpも記載しました。まだ理解が浅くどの情報があればスムーズに回答いただけるか分かっていないため、「〜のソースがほしい」と言っていただければお見せします。。。。

Comment: @DaikiYamada Topic.phpをコードブロックにしました。

Comment: モデルは問題なさそうに見えますが…。しかしSQLで`modified`とだけ書いてもエラーにならないということは、`topics`テーブルには`modified`列が無いのでは？

Comment: topicsテーブルの画像も載せました。どこかミスがあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 先程のコメントは、`topics` テーブルに `modified` 列(カラム) がないのでは、の間違いでした、すみません。
`App/tmp/cache/models/` にキャッシュファイルが生成されていたら削除してみてください。テーブル情報をキャッシュしているファイルです。
`App/Config/core.php` に記載されている `$duration` の期間は上記キャッシュファイルを見に行かず、*_list ファイルだけ参照しに行くようになっているので注意が必要です。
また、core.php の `$engine` 変数によっては上記に存在せず、memcached 上などに置かれている場合があります。

Comment: App/tmp/cache/models/のキャッシュファイルは削除しました！
【App/Config/core.php に記載されている $duration の期間は上記キャッシュファイルを見に行かず、*_list ファイルだけ参照しに行くようになっているので注意が必要です。 また、core.php の $engine 変数によっては上記に存在せず、memcached 上などに置かれている場合があります。】こちらはどういうことでしょうか。何か解決策が記載されているURLがあれば教えていただきたいです。すみません＞＜

Answer (score 2):

この回答は[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6139/cakephp%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A6modified%E3%81%8C%E6%AD%A3%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93#comment4982_6139)の説明を具体的にしたものです。
ただし、@Daiki Yamada さんは既にキャッシュファイルを削除しており、症状が解決できていないので下記対策では解決できなかったようです。
コメントだと分かり辛くなってしまいましたので、回答として記載します。
もし `App/Config/core.php` 等で設定を独自に変更している場合は当てはまらない場合がございます。

## 1.CakePHP で扱う DB や Table の情報はキャッシュされています

[App/Config/core.php：$engine](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.1/app/Config/core.php#L353)
[App/Config/core.php：$duration](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.1/app/Config/core.php#L358)

`$engine` が 'File' の場合、`App/tmp/cache/models/` 以下に DB の情報が保存されます。

@Daiki Yamada さんの状態だと、以下のようになっていると思います。

- myapp_cake_model_default_samples_myfriends_categories
- myapp_cake_model_default_samples_myfriends_comments
- myapp_cake_model_default_samples_myfriends_list
- myapp_cake_model_default_samples_myfriends_topics

`*_list` のファイルは `samples_myfriends` データベースに格納されたテーブルのリストが記されています。

`*_(db名)` のファイルは、各テーブルの情報が格納されています。

## 2.キャッシュファイルと実際のテーブルが違う場合の症状

例えば `modified` カラムを途中で追加した場合、キャッシュにはまだ `modified` カラムが存在しない状態のテーブルがキャッシュされています。
キャッシュが更新されるまでの間に `modified` カラムに関する処理を記述します。
`modified` が存在することを前提としたコードがモデルやコントローラに実装されると上記のキャッシュからテーブル情報を取得して不整合が起こり、`modified` が DB のテーブルに存在しないような振る舞いをすることがあります。

## 3. 症状の解決策

1. `App/tmp/cache/models` 以下のファイルを削除する。
2. `App/config/core.php` の `Configure::write(‘Cache.disable’, true);` のコメントを外す。

これで、ファイルキャッシュされなくなりますのでテーブル情報が反映されないということも起きなくなります。

// 言葉で説明すると難しいですね、頂いたコードを自分の環境で試したとこ(CentOS,CakePHP2.6.1,PHP5.6.4) 問題なく実行できました。
// 本当にどうしようもなくなってしまった場合は、一度環境を構築しなおすのも手かもしれません。

Comment: すごくわかりやすい・・・！指示通りにやってみましたができませんでした。しかし１からやり直すとできたので、途中どこかでミスっていたのだと思います。本通りに進めてますが、エラーになることも多いのですね。
また何かわからないことがあれば質問させていただきます。